# how to provide update services to java application?

Tags: java

I am working on a java application, my requirement is to provide online product update services to application. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/) - the software gets updated automatically, and that's handled by the web start client. You just have to provide the update.

> With Java Web Start, you launch applications simply by clicking on a Web page link. If the application is not present on your computer, Java Web Start automatically downloads all necessary files. It then caches the files on your computer so the application is always ready to be relaunched anytime you want—either from an icon on your desktop or from the browser link. And no matter which method you use to launch the application, the most current version of the application is always presented to you.